# Post to a Google+ (Google plus)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-plus

Is there anyone who knows how to post something in a Google+ stream with an iOS application?
I read everywhere that it's not possible to edit -- we can only read the posts.

Can any one confirm this, please?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: @azamsharp api is read-only, you can't post with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the official Google+ Share Link, which is now available here:
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink

Example usage:

> https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: i went throu the link. it was mainly in java script. Is it possible to implement from our android application?