# iOS - How can I share on Google+ without the intermediate share screen that the SDK shows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-plus

I have a simple iOS app which I'd like to share Urls on Google+ from. 
I have implemented their SDK (which basically calls https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com), (note: this is also noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757950/post-to-a-google-plus) SO question, but they don't really address my specific question).

But there is an intermediate screen which requires the user to press "Share". I'd like to not have to do this if possible.

I have read that the G+ API is read only, but I've noticed that Digiback (a camera app for iOS posts to Google+ no problem) shares without having any interaction.

Any advice on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the current GooglePlus SDK it is not possible to share without intermediate sharing screen.

Hope this will help you.